# Adding NOP instructions after branches and jumps for control hazards in a 5-stage RISC pipeline without hazard detection?

Tags: assembly, cpu-architecture, riscv, no-op, cpu-hazard

[image]

There is a RISCV (5 stages pipeline 32-bits) If we supose there is no hazard unit nor forwarding support, so I have to add nop instructions.

If the branch policy is Branch never taken, so we have to add nops after j loop, but also have to add nops after bge instructions? Because in the last iteration of the loop, there is a misprediction, so the processor needs these flush supposing we could have some instructions after getting out of the loop that can depend of the result of the instructions after bge (slli in this case).

I'm trying to understand how works a 5 stage pipeline riscv  processor

Comment: Don't post pictures of code, use a `code block` with triple backticks.

Comment: Are you sure your pipeline doesn't squash instructions from the wrong path for control hazards?  That's pretty different from detecting data dependencies between instructions, since the CPU does have to find out the correct path and re-steer the front-end to handle branches at all.  Marking mis-speculated instructions so they don't store or write-back is pretty simple because it's an in-order pipeline: no instructions from the wrong path have reached the EX stage before the correct direction is calculated, and for unconditional branches, it can re-steer after the ID stage.

Comment: There are no RISC V processors without bypass/forwarding for control or data hazards, but there are real MIPS RISC processors that have branch delay slots for control hazard mitigation, so you can study such architecture.

Comment: It's less that there's a branch policy, but rather that the "prediction" is simply that the next sequential instruction is what will execute next, which is sometimes wrong, of course.  This "policy" falls out of a simple implementation, assume PC + 4 as next.  To change the policy, a lot of hardware has to be added.

Comment: @ErikEidt: Properly supporting a delay slot requires extra machinery for exception handling (in case an exception is taken in the delay-slot instruction.  Exception-return needs an normal address and a "next-instruction" address.)  A super-simple pipeline that just updates PC in EX (even for unconditional branches) wouldn't properly support delay slots; you'd have to fill them with NOPs to hide branch latency. (That's why no real CPUs suck this much; it basically illustrates what that extra hardware buys you, either for killing writeback from wrong-path insns, or an architectural delay slot.)

Comment: @PeterCordes, I guess if I were implementing a branch delay slot, I would report exception that occur in the delay slot as being on the branch instead, as these branches and jumps themselves are idempotent, so re-running them upon return/resumption from exception would be ok, no?

Comment: @ErikEidt: Interesting, yeah that could work.  Unless a process is being debugged with `ptrace` single-stepping and changing regs.  If you define the ISA as potentially re-executing branch instructions, then it's software's problem if it tries to do something that would reveal the difference.  e.g. the branch is in a different page than the delay slot which is a faulting load; a user-space SIGSEGV handler unmaps the branch page because it's already done executing, and maps in a page to back the data load address.  On return, we get another invalid page fault from branch rerun.